# Python string-replace script duplicates last 1-3 lines for no apparent reason

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm completely helpless.
I created a python-script in order to automaticly rename button-names in some xaml-files, but python's string replace seems to behave very weirdly.
My script looks like this :

```
 #Tested on python3
    import fileinput
    import csv
    import random
    import glob
    import os

textToSearch = 'Button1'
with open('dict.csv', 'r') as f: 
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    your_list = list(reader)





path='F:\Release1'
type(path)
extension = 'xaml'
os.chdir(path)
result = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]


for i in range(0,len(result)):
    fileToSearch = path + '\\' + result[i] 
    tempFile = open( fileToSearch, 'r+' )

    for line in fileinput.input( fileToSearch ):
        if textToSearch in line :
            print('Match Found')
        else:
            print('Match Not Found!!')
        i=random.randint(0,717) #numbers of words in dic
        textToReplace = str(your_list[i]).replace("'","").replace("[","").replace("]","")
        tempFile.write( line.replace( textToSearch, textToReplace ) )
    tempFile.close()
    #
    #
```

When i run it, the script changes the names correctly and doesn't mess up during the process, but alway's copys some characters of the last 2-3 lines.

Like this for example :

```
  </TabControl>
        <Label x:Name="lbStatusx" Visibility="Hidden" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="212,51,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
eft" Margin="212,51,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This part is a duplicate and just corrupts the file :

```
eft" Margin="212,51,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Any pointers on what i'm doing wrong?

/edit the problem was reading and writing from the same file!
It could either be solved by writing to a new file or by calling tempFile.truncket() before writing!

Comment: You're trying to read and write to the same file at the same time.  That's likely to cause problems, particularly if the file size is changing.  I suggest writing to a new file, then renaming the new file to the old name when done.  Or you could read the entire file, close it, then open it for writing to write the new one.

Comment: Hey tom, i tried to write to output to another file, with the same result sadly. But i definitely got where you are coming from and would've been absolutely reasonable to me.

Comment: Are you sure your input file was pristine before trying it?  If you were using a stale copy, it would simply propagate the problem.

Comment: Yes, 100%.
The problem is also easily reproduceable, all I need to do is start the script and let it replace the words in a new document.
The number of chars that get appended at the end differs each time, but the file is broken every time by at least 3-5 characters.

Comment: @TomKarzes you were right!
The problem happened to be indeed that I was trying to write to the same file im reading from. I apparently ran an unupdated version of the script when trying to test your proposed solution.